# How to get sharing printer status with c#?

Tags: c#, printing, pos

I build POS system which allow user print receipt. We have 3 types of printing:

1. Print with USB
2. Print with Network (using IP address)
3. Print with Printer sharing from other pc.

I have done with case (1,2) but i not yet done with case 3.

Is it possible to solve case 3?

Comment: What specific problem are you having? With Windows, you typically just select the printer and print to it, regardless of how it's connected or where it's located.

Comment: @KenWhite: 
normaly we could print by calling printer name without check it is sharing or local printer, but in case if the sharing printer is offline we can alert to user to change to other printer for print.

Comment: So your question is about checking printer status and not about how to print to a shared printer? Then edit your question and ask that one instead. How are you dealing with a network printer that is offline?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use

> [try/catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

with exceptions. 
When You're trying to print something You can check in "try{}" is the procedure of printing correct done and then if something go wrong catch exception.

It's really hard to help You without more informations about Your program.
I can only guessing that You need

> try/catch

Comment: if we do with try catch we could check status but in case printer offline after it online it will print padding data.

Comment: Not really You musn't add everything to print queue. If printer is offline You can change printer or just say is not possible.